# Get id in bootstrap modal when button click on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I have multiple buttons to invoke a bootstrap model in a page the buttons are generated through foreach loop based on db table rows example if db table has two rows the first row id is 1, and second row id is 2 that's mean tow buttons are generated and I have set specific id to each button and i want when user click on button the bootstrap popup modal will open and display the button id in modal which one the clicked.

**I want to pas button holded id to modal within the same page**

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the following demo

View code

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC2_1Test.Models.City>

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
<a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CityName)
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CityName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <button data-id="@item.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="ModalClick"> Edit </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Modal code , `<input type="text" name="id" id="id" />` in the modal-body to get the id of button

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Details</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Id:</label>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
```

In jQuery , get the specific id of each button through `data-id="@item.Id"`, and set the id to the `<input type="text" name="id" id="id"/>` in the modal-body.

```
  @section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".btnModal").click(function () {
        var passedID = $(this).data('id');//get the id of the selected button
        $('input:text').val(passedID);//set the id to the input on the modal
    });
</script>
```

How it works

[image]

Comment: Get the data in modal without reloading page or going to controller for data, through controller its simple im also do it. give answer to relate my question please. thankyou

Comment: @ Jagdish Kumar , I have updated my reply and show how it works . The page is not reloaded when getting the id in modal .Have you tried testing the code?If you have any other issues,please share the relevant code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: its done without js, now i want to edit and delete that record without page reloading. please help